# Error invoking PDFTK when modify PDF in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdftk

I am developing `Rails 4 application` where have to `modify existing PDF file`.

User can write some comments and click then comments write in existing PDF as well. For this, i used `gem 'pdf-toolkit'`

But i got below error:

```
Error invoking PDFTK
```

My Code:

```
    my_pdf = PDF::Toolkit.open("Credit_One.pdf")
    my_pdf.updated_at = Time.now # ModDate
    my_pdf["SomeAttribute"] = "Some value"
    my_pdf.save!
```

Where is wrong any one have a idea.

Thanks

Comment: are you workinh on mac or linux? PDFTK has errors in library on MAC and needs some re installation.

Comment: linux - Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Did you consider using the `combine_pdf` gem (disclosure: I'm the author)? It's pure Ruby, so you shouldn't experience OS specific issues.